# How do I call a SOAP service in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

I'm new to Visual Studio and ASP, I need to call a SOAP service that requires passing in a username and password and responds with a Token.  I know how to do this in Javascript, but am clueless in C# / ASP.NET.

I have added the Service reference, and it seems to see that there is an issueToken call.  But I can't figure out how to use it and pass in the username and password.

I have tried searching google and on here, but everything I have found is basically "add it as a service reference and use it", but I can't figure out the use it part.  All I want is to click a button, send the call, and get a token.

This is what I have... not that it'll help.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string userName = "Name";
    string password = "Password";
    TokenService.issueToken callToken = new TokenService.issueToken();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll look something like this:

```
string userName = "Name";
string password = "Password";
var proxy = new TokenServiceClient();
var token = proxy.issueToken(userName, password);
proxy.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to instantiate the Service before.

```
TokenService myService = new TokenService();
myService.YourDesiredMethod(userName, password);
```

Seems like you tried to call a static Method on the Service.